# Multiple separate waypoints with bing map

Tags: maps, bing-maps

I want your help to resolve the issue. On Bing Map i am trying to display multiple source and destination for the same i used [Bing MAP](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/directionscreatedrivingroute#JS). But it is connecting all the waypoint from each other. I want separate waypoint for each source and destination.

In the below code i want to draw separate line between Waypoint 1 (Redmond)  and 2 (Seattle). Also a separate waypoint between Waypoint2 (TAXAS) to waypoint3(Orlando) . I want to design the image as [image]

```
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    /* No need to set credentials if already passed in URL */
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.606209, -122.332071),
    zoom: 12
});
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
    // Set Route Mode to driving
    directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });
    var waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Redmond', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67683029174805, -122.1099624633789) });
    var waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Seattle', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.59977722167969, -122.33458709716797) });
    var waypoint3 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'TAXAS', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(31.000000, -100.000000) });
    var waypoint4 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Orlando', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(28.538336, -81.379234) });
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint3);
     directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint4);
    // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
    directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('printoutPanel') });
    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single directions manager can only maintain a single route at a time. If you want to show multiple, disconnected routes, you will need a separate directions manager for each route. There is an official sample for this scenario from the Bing Maps team here: https://samples.bingmapsportal.com/?sample=display-multiple-routes

Comment: Thank you. Can i change point name A to B with different name . I want to add custom text for A and B.

Comment: You can override the start and end text, and even add more. You can apply a single style to all waypoints in between.

```
directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
 firstWaypointPushpinOptions: { text: '1', title: 'Start', subTitle: 'Go' },
 waypointPushpinOptions: { text: '2', title: 'Mid-Point', subTitle: 'Half way there' },
 lastWaypointPushpinOptions: { text: '3', title: 'End', subTitle: 'You did it!' }
});
```